# Constant Variables in PHP after page reloads

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

im very new to PHP, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

**So here is the scenario.**

Im writing a PHP all in one page that gets a random word from an array, scrambles the word, then lets the user guess the word.

now im using the isset(), so it declares the variable, then once submit is clicked, it will get in user input via _POST().

**Now the problem**
I need the calculated variable to remain constant, but once the page reloads, it regenerates the variable.

is there anyway i can get pass this?

```
<?php

        function GetShuffWord()
        {
             $arrayName     = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5');
             $randWordIndex = rand(0,4);
             $randomWord    = $arrayName[$randWordIndex];
             $shuffledWord = str_shuffle($randomWord);
             return $shuffledWord;
        }

        if(!isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
            define("shuffledWord", GetShuffWord());
            $tempWord = shuffledWord;

            // showing the user shuffled word
            echo " <h1 style='font-size: 50px' align = 'center'> {$tempWord}
            </h1>";
        }
        else
        {
            $tempWord = shuffledWord;
            echo " <h1 style='font-size: 50px' align = 'center'>{$tempWord} </h1>";
            echo "else part";
        }
    ?>
```

another problem is that if i declare the variable in the if, i cannot use variable in the else with out re-generating it.

Comment: This is where "persistent" storage is appropriate, perhaps consider using session

Comment: Please post some of your existing code. The solution will be to store the value in `$_SESSION` so it persists across a page load. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php and [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Good day Mark and Michael, will the session variable not get reset when the page loads?

Comment: @user2770112 no it won't you just need to start your session; just read about session in the manual

Answer (score 2):

You can just include the value as a hidden input field in your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myCalculatedValue" value="<?= $tempWord ?>" />
```

Then when the form is submitted you can just get it via `$_POST['myCalculatedValue']`

Comment: If you are pleased with the answer can you up-vote it and mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session and put a check that if session has it already dont overwrite.

And when u want to overwrite you can do so as well by passing another flag to the script in your post request.